# One Signal Notification Delivered but not receiving notification

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, notifications

I have set up one signal SDK in my application to receive push notifications , i have gone through the documentation and made everything , when i go on dashbord , i push a new notification , it says delivered but not receiving any notification , any reason why , thank you .

- Init One Signal

```
   OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.INFO);
        OneSignal.initWithContext(this);
        OneSignal.setAppId(ONE_SIGNAL_ID);
```